# UNIX gunzip command

Tags: unix, gunzip

gunzip will unzip the gz file and displays the result

Is there any option to get list of files/file name that were compressed to .gz file

eg:sample.gz contains 2 files

file1.txt
abc

file2.txt
def

gunzip -c sample.gz 
o/p:abc
def

But I need file names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gzip just compresses. It is not an archive format, so a gzipped file cannot "contain" anything. You can put a bunch of files into a tar archive and then gzip that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions and questions on
*using*  Unix commands are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

This question would be more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (if you’re running Ubuntu).

Comment: *If* you have a gzipped tar file, you can use `tar tzf sample.tar.gz`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `gunzip -l` option to see the name of file which will be uncompressed.

Comment: This is unfortunately incorrect. `gzip` does not store the filename in the compressed contents. The "uncompressed" name that `-l` shows is just created by removing .gz from the end of the filename you provide. You can see this by renaming the file and then doing a `-l` again.

Comment: Hi Adam, Did u mean gunzip the  file and rename it and do -l  on the renamed file. I tried it but it is throwing error no such file or dir. Please correct me if I am wrong.